# how can I make my image (down arrow) disappear when I start scrolling my page?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following page http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/20/ and there's this white square that in the future will be the link to the area below - how can I make so when user starts scrolling down then this icon will disappear? 
so far the css for this arrow looks like this:

```
.next-section {
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:white;
    background-image:url(../img/next_section.png); 
    background-size: 34px 18px; 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-position:13px 21px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-30px;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

I'm just not sure if I can do it only in CSS or should I use some jquery here (also - I don't know how to do it here)... 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a bit of jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {// can be whatever, 0 refers to the top space you allow
        $('.move').hide();// Hide your element
    }
    else {
        $('.move').show();// It's just if you want to show back the element if we're back on top
    }
});
```

Take note that I, according to your fiddle masked the link (.move) and not just the inner div.

Hope it's gonna help you

---

If you want to show back, take a note to the comment of Juan C and use his code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".move").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0);
});
```

Comment: he would have to show it when he's back at the top, you could change to be this instead of the 'if' $(".move").toggle($(this).scrollTop() === 0);    http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/21/

Answer (score 0):

i think it can solve what you are looking for

```
setInterval(function(){
var scrl =    parseInt($("body").scrollTop());
var hei = parseInt($("#fadeAway").height());
var tt = (hei * scrl) / 100;
   if(tt <= 100){
        tt = parseInt(tt / 10);
        tt = parseFloat("0."+tt);
        var tt2 = parseFloat(1.0 - tt);
        $("#fadeAway").css({"opacity":tt2});
   }
},100);
```

you can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wm24tv3/1/)